# AssertionError: assertion failed: copyAndReset must return a zero value copy

Tags: apache-spark, apache-beam

When I applied `ParDo.of(new ParDoFn())` to `PCollection` named `textInput`, The program throws this Exception. But The Program is normal when I delete `.apply(ParDo.of(new ParDoFn()))`.

//SparkRunner

```
private static void testHadoop(Pipeline pipeline){
    Class<? extends FileInputFormat<LongWritable, Text>> inputFormatClass =
            (Class<? extends FileInputFormat<LongWritable, Text>>)
                    (Class<?>) TextInputFormat.class;
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")  //hdfs://localhost:9000
            HadoopIO.Read.Bound<LongWritable, Text> readPTransfom_1 = HadoopIO.Read.from("hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp/kinglear.txt",
            inputFormatClass,
            LongWritable.class,
            Text.class);
    PCollection<KV<LongWritable, Text>> textInput = pipeline.apply(readPTransfom_1)
            .setCoder(KvCoder.of(WritableCoder.of(LongWritable.class), WritableCoder.of(Text.class)));

    //OutputFormat
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Class<? extends FileOutputFormat<LongWritable, Text>> outputFormatClass =
            (Class<? extends FileOutputFormat<LongWritable, Text>>)
                    (Class<?>) TemplatedTextOutputFormat.class;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    HadoopIO.Write.Bound<LongWritable, Text> writePTransform = HadoopIO.Write.to("hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp/output", outputFormatClass, LongWritable.class, Text.class);

    textInput.apply(ParDo.of(new ParDoFn())).apply(writePTransform.withoutSharding());

    pipeline.run().waitUntilFinish();

}
```

Comment: Can you please include the full exception stack trace in your question? This would help narrow down the problem for sure. Also, you may want to try to follow style in the Apache Beam examples -- the transforms you construct are used once; you may want to inline them, and your code will be much more readable.

Answer (score 4):

I was facing similar issue when I created custom accumulator that extends `org.apache.spark.util.AccumulatorV2`. The cause was improper logic in  `override def isZero: Boolean` method. So basically when you `copyAndReset` method called by default it calls `copy()` then `reset()` your `isZero()` should return true.
If you look at the AccumulatorV2 source that is where is a check is:

```
// Called by Java when serializing an object
final protected def writeReplace(): Any = {
 if (atDriverSide) {
   if (!isRegistered) {
     throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
       "Accumulator must be registered before send to executor")
   }
   val copyAcc = copyAndReset()
   assert(copyAcc.isZero, "copyAndReset must return a zero value copy")
   copyAcc.metadata = metadata
   copyAcc
 } else {
   this
 }
}
```

specifically this part

```
 val copyAcc = copyAndReset()
 assert(copyAcc.isZero, "copyAndReset must return a zero value copy")
```

Hope it helps. Happy sparking!

Answer (score 3):

Which Spark version are you running on top ? From my experience the error you're getting is thrown by Spark 2.x AccumulatorV2, Spark runner currently supports Spark 1.6.

Comment: @zifanpan can you explain how did you fix this. I have same dependency version as you suggested i.e. 1.6.3, am not able to fix this. please suggest