# Scala/Spark tests failing with "copyAndReset must return a zero value copy"

Tags: scala, apache-spark

After switching Spark framework from 1.6 to 2.1, running my tests results in many occurrences of the following error:

```
[info]   java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: copyAndReset must return a zero value copy
[info]   at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:170)
[info]   at org.apache.spark.util.AccumulatorV2.writeReplace(AccumulatorV2.scala:163)
[info]   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
[info]   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[info]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
[info]   at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteReplace(ObjectStreamClass.java:1075)
[info]   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1136)
[info]   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
[info]   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
[info]   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
[info]   ...
```

Any ideas what's happening and how I can fix this?

Comment: It seems that somewhere your code (or 3rd party libraries you're using) assume an earlier version of Spark - specifically, using the older Accumulators API which is deprecated in 2.X - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42336251/assertionerror-assertion-failed-copyandreset-must-return-a-zero-value-copy

Comment: Ah, indeed I found references to the old accumulator.  Thanks!