# CopyAndReset must return a zero value copy

Tags: apache-spark, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I want to run a wordcount example in a spark cluster, which is provided by apache beam.
But when I submit this project to spark, it throws this exception.

The same problem with [Same problem in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42336251/assertionerror-assertion-failed-copyandreset-must-return-a-zero-value-copy/47298294#47298294)
But my spark cluster is v2.0.0, that can not solve it by change spark version to v1.6.0.
Any idea to solve this problem without change spark version?

```
  17/11/15 09:51:38 WARN SparkConf: In Spark 1.0 and later spark.local.dir will be overridden by the value set by the cluster manager (via SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS in mesos/standalone and LOCAL_DIRS in YARN).
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: copyAndReset must return a zero value copy
        at org.apache.beam.runners.spark.SparkPipelineResult.runtimeExceptionFrom(SparkPipelineResult.java:55)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.spark.SparkPipelineResult.beamExceptionFrom(SparkPipelineResult.java:72)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.spark.SparkPipelineResult.waitUntilFinish(SparkPipelineResult.java:99)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.spark.SparkPipelineResult.waitUntilFinish(SparkPipelineResult.java:87)
        at org.apache.beam.examples.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:219)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:729)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:185)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:210)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: copyAndReset must return a zero value copy
    at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.util.AccumulatorV2.writeReplace(AccumulatorV2.scala:157)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteReplace(ObjectStreamClass.java:1118)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1136)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:43)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:295)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2037)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1.apply(RDD.scala:763)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1.apply(RDD.scala:762)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:358)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.mapPartitions(RDD.scala:762)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.mapPartitionsToPair(JavaRDDLike.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.mapPartitionsToPair(JavaRDDLike.scala:45)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.spark.translation.TransformTranslator$6.evaluate(TransformTranslator.java:393)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.spark.translation.TransformTranslator$6.evaluate(TransformTranslator.java:351)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.spark.SparkRunner$Evaluator.doVisitTransform(SparkRunner.java:412)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.spark.SparkRunner$Evaluator.visitPrimitiveTransform(SparkRunner.java:398)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:602)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:594)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:594)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:594)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.access$500(TransformHierarchy.java:276)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:210)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.traverseTopologically(Pipeline.java:440)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.spark.SparkRunner$2.run(SparkRunner.java:211)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: I too am running into the same issue.  Will continue digging around and respond if I find anything of value.